# OpenXML syntax for adding a hyperlink to an .XLSX document cell when using Datatables.js

Tags: javascript, excel, datatables, openxml, xlsx

I have tried everything I can think of and find and nothing works. Even ChatGPT's answers don't work.

I'm using [Datatables.js](https://datatables.net/) and I'm customizing the `excel` export button functionality so that I can create a hyperlink where the text in a cell is a URL.

So I:

- I find the cell I need
- Create a `<Relationship>` tag and add the necessary attributes to point to the respective cell
- Inject the `<Relationship>` tag into the `<Relationships>` doc

then I:

- Create a `<hyperlink>` element
- Add the necessary attributes to point to the `<Relationship>` tag
- Append the `<hyperlink>` tag to the cell's `<c>` tag

So in the end, the cell's syntax looks like this:

```
<c t="inlineString" r="E54">
    <is>
        <hyperlink r:id="rId3" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
            <t>Click here</t>
        </hyperlink>
    </is>
</c>
```

Where the relationship syntax looks like this:

```
<Relationship Id="rId3" Target="https://google.com" TargetMode="External" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink"></Relationship>
```

Here, I'm editing the workbook relationships. There is one other instance of the relationships that I can find (see image below), but using that set doesn't change the behavior, unfortunately.

[image]

The code (if you open up the browser console, run this snippet, click on export to excel, then you can see the relationships and cell XML in the console):

```js
const options = {
    dom: 'B',
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'Survey Reports', className: 'btn-sm', text: 'Export to excel',
            customize: function(xlsx, button, dt, config) {

                // Get the sheet data for the first sheet in the .xlsx file
                const sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml']
                const relationships = xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].querySelector('Relationships')
                const rows = sheet.querySelectorAll('row')

                // Adding an attribute to the worksheetElem element
                const worksheetElem = sheet.querySelector('worksheet')
                worksheetElem.setAttribute('xmlns:xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')

                // Loop through each row
                rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {

                    // Get all cells in the row
                    const rowCells = row.querySelectorAll('c')

                    // Loop through cells
                    rowCells.forEach(cell => {

                        // Counting the relationships to give the correct number to the rel ID
                        let relsAmount = relationships.children.length
                        relsAmount++

                        // Get the <is> tag inside the cell
                        const cellInnerElem = cell.querySelector('is')

                        // Create the relationship element
                        const relElem = `<Relationship Id="rId${relsAmount}" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="https://google.com" TargetMode="External"></Relationship>`

                        // Add the relationship element into the relationships doc
                        relationships.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', relElem)

                        // Remove the <t> tag from the cell
                        cellInnerElem.querySelector('t').remove()

                        // Update the cell to include the hyperlink with a new <t> tag
                        const link = `<hyperlink r:id="rId${relsAmount}"><t>Click here</t></hyperlink>`
                        cellInnerElem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', link)
                    })
                })
                console.log(relationships)
                console.log(rows[0].querySelector('c'))
            }
        }
    ]
}

let table = $('table').DataTable(options);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<table id="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td>Some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td>Some data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please find a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/za6y2nt4/). 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot this, despite the fact that you put so much work into this post. An easier way would be to see an example of an Excel file that you need it to be and compare it against an Excel file that you generate (like with the code above) so that we can inspect the SpreadsheetML to see where the discrepancy may be. You can do this on your own as well. Use the OpenXMLDiff tool that comes with the OpenXML SDK.

Comment: I agree with Todd but one thing that is definitely incorrect is that you are creating the relationship for the workbook when it is a relationship for the worksheet.

Comment: Hey @ToddMain. Thanks for checking this out. I created a JS fiddle here where it should allow you to download the xlsx file: https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/za6y2nt4/. But thanks for that tip. I think I'll definitely get that tool and inspect the XML.

Comment: Hey @AndrewS. Thanks for the tip! I created a JS fiddle here where it should allow you to download the xlsx file: jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/za6y2nt4. As for the relationships, I looked at what else is available and I can only find one other instance of the relationships, but it still doesn't work as expected. I updated the question to reflect what I'm talking about.

Comment: Another way to consider doing this is to find a way from your library to insert a formula into cells you need, like `=HYPERLINK("https://google.com","Click here")`.

Comment: Thanks @ToddMain I appreciate you guys looking at my Q. I tried that hyperlink formula, but unfortunately it still just parsed as a string. So I actually took a different direction now intercepting the Datatables export function and using the ExcelJS library to create the .xlsx file and parse those hyperlinks. Seems to work smoothly. I think I'll add the answer once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by utilizing the HYPERLINK func. You need to create the following xml structure in your cell:

```
<c t="str" r="A2"><f xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","go GOOGLE!")</f><v xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">go GOOGLE!</v></c>
```